# Run Windows Server 2011 in kiosk mode and hide windows all together

Tags: windows, group-policy, kiosk

I want to configure windows on boxes that I can ship to customers that needs to be deprived of any "windows" brand.

In fact, I created a web server running on this windows box to configure the parts of the system that I want my users to be able to configure (like ip settings).

When my users plug a monitor/keyboard into this box to see "what's going on under the hood of this server", I want them to land on the login page of this web-app (preferably using Google Chrome in full-screen mode).

Here's the list of things I do not want:

- No windows login screen
- No windows logo anywhere
- No Start Menu or
- TaskBar No Window "Chrome" (maximize, minimize, menubar, status bar)
- No error message on CTRL-ALT-DEL, WINDOWS-PAUSE, etc

So basically, from the user perspective, the thing could be running linux or ChromeOS it should not appear as running windows.

Of course I maintain RDP capabilities (on a different port) to service the box if something was to happen.

Any idea of a combination of group policies or third-party software that could help me do this?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Sounds like you really want a different shell for different users on your computer.  You would opt to set the shell for the general user to Chrome launched into kiosk mode (if possible).

[MSDN - Different Shells for Different Users](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms838576%28v=WinEmbedded.5%29.aspx)